# Sulu CMS: PDOException / database connextion after new installation

Tags: sulu

I followed [this installation guide for Sulu CMS](http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/book/getting-started.html). But get this database error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 
'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' 
(using password: NO)'
```

This is the parameters.yml file:

## This file is auto-generated during the composer install

```
parameters:
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: localhost
database_port: null
database_name: sulu-cms
database_user: root
database_password: root
database_version: 5.6
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: localhost
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
sulu_admin.name: Sulu
sulu_admin.email: null
websocket_port: 9876
websocket_url: sulu.lo
phpcr_backend:
type: doctrinedbal
phpcr_workspace: default
phpcr_user: admin
phpcr_pass: admin
phpcr_cache: file_system
```

Comment: You have not to your Database, password or username incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the mysql username and password are correct?

Comment: No, but the default username and password should be: "root" and the password "" (empty)

Comment: But your password is set to "root", not to an empty string.